# Doing a countdown in React

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, countdown

I'm trying to work out how to do a pre-game countdown in a Game component in React. I'm trying like this, but it's saying that `this.countDown` isn't a function - when it's clearly defined.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

```js
class Game extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      timer: 5,
      isHidden: true,
      randomIndex: 0,
      score: 0
    };

    this.countDown = this.countDown.bind(this);
  }

  countDown() {
    this.setState({
      timer: this.state.timer--
    });
  }

  render() {
    const tables = this.props.tables.map(table => {
      return (
        <li key={table.uniqueId}>
          {table.timesTable[0]} X {table.timesTable[1]}
        </li>
      );
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      this.countDown();
      console.log(this.state.timer);
    }, 1000);

    // if (this.state.timer > 0) {
    //     this.countDown();
    // }

    return (
      <div className="Game">
        <h3>Current Tables are:</h3>
        {tables}
        <h1 id="countdown">{this.state.timer}</h1>
        <Question />
        {/* question handles the right or wrong logic, receives a random timestable */}
        <h3>Score: {this.state.score}</h3>
        <button onClick={this.stopGame}>Stop Game</button>
        <button onClick={this.startOver}>Start Over</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Game;
```

Comment: Inside setInterval use arrow function or bind this, this is not accessible in callbacks in case of normal functions

Comment: Brilliant thank you - I thought it was some sort of scoping error. I'm guessing my this was referring to the setInterval?

Comment: Ya actually in normal functions ( non arrow or without binding this ) this points to object from where it is called and as setInterval takes it as callback, so it won't be called from your object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that example, `this` in `setInterval`'s callback refers to the `global window` object, since it's executed as `window.setInterval(...)`, so `this.countDown()` would be equal to `window.countDown()`, which is obviously incorrect.

To get `this` from parent's scope, you could use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.countDown();
  console.log(this.state.timer)
}, 1000);
```

or simply [bind this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
setInterval(function() {
  this.countDown();
  console.log(this.state.timer)
}.bind(this), 1000); // bind this from parent's scope
```